# Creating a new table row and data cell with text from an input tag on button click JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I want to create something similar to a cart whenever a user clicks on a button called "Add"
Use case: Every time a user inputs an expense amount, a date, and a payment description, then selects add, I want to append a row to the cart table with the information.

```
<body>
    <div id="outerBox">
        <fieldset id="tableContainer">
            <legend>Create A New Expense</legend>
            <table id="expTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Amount Due</th>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <th>Recurring Monthly Charge?</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="amt"><apex:InputField value="{!Expense__c.Payment_Amount__c}"/></td>
                        <td id="dueDate"><apex:InputField value="{!Expense__c.Description__c}"/></td>
                        <td id="dueDate"><apex:InputField value="{!Expense__c.Next_Due_Date__c}"/
</td>
                        <td><apex:InputField value="{!Expense__c.Recurring_Monthly_Bill__c}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div id="add">Add</div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="bucket">
        <fieldset id="bucketContainter">
            <legend>Added Expenses</legend>
            <table id="bucketTable" cellspacing="5px" width="400px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="picContainer">
        <apex:image styleClass="hatchet" value="{!$Resource.hatchet}"/>
    </div>
</body>

For the JQuery so far I have
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add').click(function(){

        $('#picContainer').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#bucket').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#bucketTable tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
       //How do I put the input value from the text fields in the inner html of the <td>?
    });
});
```

My main question is how do I pull the input field value from my first table and add its contents to the innerHTML of the of my data cells in my bucket table?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you create a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `td` all have ID's, you should be able to do this: (I'm not sure how `apex` controls work, someone correct if this is not the proper way to pull a value out):

```
$('#bucketTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + $("#amt").children().val() + '</td><td>' + $("#dueDate").children().val() + '</td><td>' + $("#dueDate2").children().val() + '</td></tr>');
```

Also, your `dueDate` ID is there twice, this will cause errors. Change that! (in the code above, I made it `dueDate2`)

Comment: Thanks for the response, everything is right except there is one minor change for apex input fields. I moved the ID to the input field instead of the data cell. And instead of #amt I used "[id$=amt]", thanks for helping me get to the solution!

Comment: Ahh, nice. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fpgT2/1/

change the duplicate "dueDate" id in your html to use "desc", like this:

```
<td id="amt"><apex:InputField value="{!Expense__c.Payment_Amount__c}"/></td>
<td id="desc"><apex:InputField value="{!Expense__c.Description__c}"/></td>
<td id="dueDate"><apex:InputField value="{!Expense__c.Next_Due_Date__c}"/></td>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add').click(function(){

        $('#picContainer').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#bucket').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#bucketTable tbody').append('<tr><td id="hd-duedate"></td><td id="hd-desc"></td><td id="hd-amt"></td></tr>');
       //How do I put the input value from the text fields in the inner html of the <td>?

        $("#hd-duedate").text( $("#duedate").children().val() );
        $("#hd-desc").text( $("#desc").children().val() );
        $("#hd-amt").text( $("#amt").children().val() );
    });
});
```